# When to use SQLAlchemy and when to use Pandas for data manipulation

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I understand we can use SQLAlchemy to import data from the database. But why would one choose SQLAlchemy to manipulate data when you can simply just import it and convert it to a dataframe and then manipulate it using pandas and other python libraries.

I know this is an opinion based question, but I think it is important to know the difference especially that importing data and manipulating data is quite time consuming. One can save a lot of time by identifying the correct method to use thus saving StackOverflow many questions on a specific topic.

So more precisely, why use SQL Alchemy for manipulating data when pandas suffice. Is there specific cases where SQL Alchemy beats pandas.

### Update

When I say manipulate, I refer to adding, subtracting, counting, calculating percentages or averages i.e mathematical functions and other data manipulation techniques (Grouping, sorting, appending, order in descending or ascending order...).

Comment: This question is not quite correct as Pandas uses SQL Alchemy internally... :-)

Comment: @MaxU if pandas use SQL Alchemy internally, then what is the use of SQL Alchemy beside connecting to the engine and importing data ? I am so confused on the existence of SQL Alchemy data manipulation when pandas suffice in many functions.

Comment: You don't use SQLAlchemy for manipulating data, but abstracting communication with your database and mapping between the relational and object model. You then query data from your database in various ways.

Comment: there are tons of programs, that don't use Pandas, but they are using SQL Alchemy... So your question is similar to "why one would need an engine if there is Bugatti/Lamborgini out there"

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks for the answer, you cleared more doubt. What do you mean by __abstract communication__ ?

Comment: @Victor SQLAlchemy casts data from your database into Python objects which is why it's known as an ORM (Object Relational Mapper). Then in your code, you can just worry about dealing with your Python objects, and SQLAlchemy will automatically serialise to/from your database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example when you want to use both Pandas and SQL Alchemy:

Imagine that you need to update a DB table (let's say it has 100.000.000 rows and doesn't fit in memory) from the DataFrame (that has 100.000 rows). I.e. there is a column `ID` in your DF and you want to update a column in the DB table for those ID's using data from the DF. In this case you can dump your DF into a DB as a table and execute `UPDATE ...` statement using SQL Alchemy.

Here is a small demo:

```
df.to_sql('tmp', conn, if_exists='replace')

sql = """
UPDATE table_name set last_seen = (SELECT t.last_seen
                                   FROM tmp t
                                   WHERE t.id = table_name.id)
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM tmp
    WHERE tmp.id = table_name.id
)
"""

cursor.execute(sql)
```